# MySQL - how to count difference for each row & field?

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
Date   | Item A   | Item B   | Item C   | Item D
------------------------------------------------
1/1/16 | 1        | 0        | 3        | 1
1/2/16 | 3        | 3        | 4        | 0
1/3/16 | 10       | 4        | 8        | 1
1/4/16 | 5        | 3        | 8        | 3
```

The output should be a new table consisting of the difference of the value of each Item compared to the day before. The output of the sample table would be a new table with the following contents:

```
Date   | Item A   | Item B   | Item C   | Item D
------------------------------------------------
1/2/16 | 2        | 3        | 1        | -1
1/3/16 | 7        | 1        | 4        | 1
1/4/16 | -5       | -1       | 0        | 2
```

I would like to achieve this with a single MySQL command. I have currently something along the lines of:

```
SELECT SUM(Item A) AS DIFF 
FROM my_table
WHERE date = '1/1/16'
```

which outputs me "1". But this is not close to what I am looking for...

Thank you for the help and input.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single query. Either a mysql procedure or a loop in php / other language. You can get the diff for 2 days by joining the table with itself (once with date1, once with date2). Then repeat for all days. If this is enough, I can post the query as an answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Else take a look at user-defined variables to store the result of the previous row: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: @Marki555 - that sounds good enough for me and I would be interested in your code/answer

Answer (score 0):

To compute difference between 2 rows of the same table, you need to JOIN the table with itself, so that you can have values from 2 rows in the same row inside the query.

To test it:

```
SELECT t1.ItemA, t2.ItemA, t1.ItemA-t2.ItemA AS DiffA, 
       t1.ItemB, t2.ItemB, t1.ItemB-t2.ItemB AS DiffB
FROM my_table t1, my_table t2
WHERE t1.date = '1/2/16' AND
      t2.date = '1/1/16'
```

NOTE: Depending on the exact field type of `ItemA`, you may need to do this instead (it was needed in my case): `CAST(t1.ItemA AS signed) - CAST(t2.ItemA AS signed) AS DiffA`

Comment: Please use explicit joins, not year 1995 joins using the `from`  clause